Problem with table is LateX when i try to put a little advanced table
I've been trying to find a solution for this table, the rest is easy but the first 3 rows gave me a hard time. The problem is that HCI is always under EP2 instead of interaction
This is what i tried:

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
EP.2 & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{EP1} & Interaction \\ \hline
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Méthodes d'expression des émotions} & \\ \hline
     & Tâches passives & Tâches actives & Tâches passives + actives & HCI & HHI \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description des différentes bases de données}
\label{tab:bases-donnees}
\end{table}



Please always include a compilable [mre] in your questions, not just a code fragment.

your multicolumns length should be set to 3, not 4. try this one,
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
{EP.2}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{EP.1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Interaction}  \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
     &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Methodes d'expression des emotions} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}\\ \cmidrule{2-6}
     & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches \\ passives\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches \\ actives\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches passives \\ + actives\end{tabular}    & HCI & HHI \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description des differentes bases de donnees}
\label{tab:bases-donnees}
\end{table} 

which gives out the following output,

I'd prefer to discard vertical lines though,
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}}
\hline
{EP.2}&\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{EP.1}  & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{Interaction}  \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
     &  \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Methodes d'expression des emotions} &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{}\\ \cmidrule{2-6}
     & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches \\ passives\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches \\ actives\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Taches passives \\ + actives\end{tabular}    & HCI & HHI \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Description des differentes bases de donnees}
\label{tab:bases-donnees}
\end{table}

which results in

